# How can I Implement transparent status bar or navigation bar for a specific composable in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm currently working with Jetpack Compose and I've run into a bit of a snag. I'm looking to make the status bar and navigation bar transparent for a particular composable in my app, without affecting the rest of the application. I have researched this extensively but haven't found a clear solution.

Is there a way to achieve this in Jetpack Compose? I've given a shot at a few approaches and code snippets, but none seem to work as expected.

If anyone has experience or tips on how to implement a transparent status bar or navigation bar specifically for one composable, I'd be extremely grateful for your insights.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution is do the following before `setContent{` on the onCreate:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    window.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
    )
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)    
    this.actionBar?.hide()

    setContent {

     .
     .
     .
```

Comment: It will be applied to the whole app rather on a single composable

Comment: This is for the MainActivity for the whole app

Comment: My problem, when app splash screen open then splesh screen also have trensparent statusBar which i dont need but for other activities i need transparent status bar 

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
        )
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        installSplashScreen()
        setContent {
           ...
        }

Comment: @IamAyanMishra make the composables you need to show status bar one Activity and another activity the composables you need to hide status bar